# What is the value for markerLength in ArUco estimatePoseSingleMarkers?

Tags: aruco

For this function in ArUco sample,             aruco::estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, markerLength, camMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);

What is the markerLength value? How do I calculate the value?

The documentation is here. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#ga84dd2e88f3e8c3255eb78e0f79571bd1

But I'm not sure what it means actually.

Answer (score 0):

Your printed ArUco markers have a certain size and you should input it here. As denoted in the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#ga84dd2e88f3e8c3255eb78e0f79571bd1) you linked, the resulting translation vector will be in the same unit as the one you used for the maker length.

The function need the real size of the marker to be able to know if a marker is "big but far away" or "small and close to the camera".